# What's this kind of chicken products package called?

Tags: image-identification

What's this kind of chicken products package called?
In my language it's simply called "**package**" (this is the translation), but I'm asking about this specific kind. Someone told me maybe it is called "**tray**". Is it what you call it as native English speakers?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This can get rather involved, depending on context. In everyday AmE lingo: package or pack or tray pack. (not just tray).

Comment: Please give a real-world context where you'd like to use this word, if it exists.

Comment: Please, here are some contexts for instance: 1) As an advertisement above the products in supermarket. 2) Let's suppose that I am a teacher and want to ask my students to use this kind of package for some experiment. 3) I want to describe to my friend which of the packages exactly to buy in the supermarket (It's much more comfortable to use what I was told that it's called 'tray').

Comment: What does real world context mean? A picture is real-world context.

Comment: Is he ordering such trays from a packaging company?  Asking a recycling company whether that kind of packaging is recyclable? Does he need to know the term of art as used by people knowledgeable about packaging, or would a periphrasis suffice (e.g. " foam tray from some refrigerated chicken you bought at the supermarket").  That's what I mean, @Lambie.

Answer (score 9):

**Pack** or **package** would be perfectly acceptable. If you wanted to get more technical, you might say that it was a **shrink-wrapped package**.

Comment: But this one can also be "shrink wrapped package"  and it's something totally else.   http://contents.i.sdska.ru/_i/news/c/74/temp/chelru/sdelano/2013/kurica_good.jpg?_200.  Would you not use the word "tray"? How are you used to see it called in supermarkets around you?

Comment: No, we generally would not use the word 'tray'. Including in supermarkets. Supermarkets would just use 'pack' or 'package'.

Comment: tray packs is the technical term, by the way. Also, I  think BrE speakers would say packet.

Comment: "Tray" would be what you call the yellow styrofoam thing. With the chicken and plastic wrap, it's a "package" or "pack".

Comment: In supermarkets, we don't  necessarily even bother to say pack. We ***say*** I'm buying some chicken legs or chicken thighs etc. And when you tell someone to pick some up at the grocery store, you say that too. You would only use it if you are buying more than one pack/packages.

Comment: If further detail was needed, I might describe the illustrated item as a "peel-open pack." I think the items in the question are heat sealed, or perhaps ultrasonically welded, rather than shrink-wrapped. The latter would typically conform to the contours of whatever is inside.

Answer (score 4):

In response to your question what would you tell your friends who you sends to the supermarket to buy some chicken:  Most likely I would ask them to get a "package" or several "packages" of (uncooked) chicken.

The challenge is that each supermarket might package its chicken in a different way.  Some use *trays* like the one in your picture.  Some will sell similar items in *bags*.  Of course, you can also buy *whole chickens* in various ways.

"Package" works because it covers most of the options.  It doesn't matter how the chicken is *packaged*, as long as you bring back one (or more) of those *packages*.

That being said, you'll probably have to explicitly say what part of the chicken you want, and whether you want it with or without bones:

> Could you pick up a couple of packages of **boneless chicken thighs**?
>
> Could you pick up a couple of packages of **drumsticks and wings**?
>
> Could you pick up a **whole chicken**, but cut into pieces?

and also whether you want it raw or cooked -- many supermarkets offer whole cooked chickens for relatively low cost, and your friends might be confused.

> Could you pick us up a **cooked (rotisserie) chicken** for dinner?

In any case, chicken is normally sold by *weight* so it's more common to tell someone how *much* you need, rather than focus on the packaging.

Comment: There can be different sizes of packs, so it's not a typical unit of measure for shopping.  If you were planning a recipe, you'd be much more likely to ask someone to pick up "around 800 grams of chicken breast", which have plans to use in 2 separate meals.  Leave it up to them whether to find 2 small packs or one large pack.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase **[foam tray](https://www.google.com/search?q=foam%20tray&num=20&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPjO2r3q7fAhWjh1QKHc2xBYEQ_AUIDygC&biw=1473&bih=861)** is generic and encompasses a wide range of applications, not just the tray on which meat and poultry are placed in the refrigerated bins and on the refrigerated shelves of the supermarket.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please, refer to the situation where you send your friends to the supermarket to buy some chicken. How would you say "Please, bring one "chicken wings tray" or "chicken wings foam tray"?

Comment: I really don't understand your question. If I'm sending  someone to the supermarket to buy chicken, I would ask for the kind of meat and the weight or the number, as the case may call for. *Please get about a pound of chicken thighs* or *Please get two chicken breasts* or *Please get about eight drumsticks*.  The packaging would be irrelevant.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - in some Russian stores chicken is sold "by-package", with the packages marked with price, so it would be a common turn of phrase, "bring a (kilogram) package of chicken breasts".

Comment: @CowperKettle: In the US, chicken is also placed in such packages in supermarkets. But there is no variety in the packaging itself, only varying weight and varying number of pieces and varying combinations of pieces.  So every package has a slightly different price, since the packaged meat is sold by weight. The packaging is never a relevant component of such a request. No one asks for a package of chicken but for an amount of chicken.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, I think your comments could usefully go into the answer. I'd offer the caveat that one *might* say something like "get a roaster chicken—not the [packaged kind](https://www.springermountainfarms.com/whole-chicken-cutup), a whole chicken" (or vice versa).

Comment: @1006: That's a whole chicken. We're talking chicken parts here :)

Comment: My wife just tells me to go get a pound of chicken. I look for a package as close the the specified weight that I can find.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You can get *the equivalent of* a whole chicken, cut up, in the kind of package the OP describes. So there are occasions when I have specified "packaged" chicken rather than just a weight (or specified whole, *not* packaged). Dinner is complicated!

Answer (score 2):

I asked a friend who works in the chicken processing industry (in Pennsylvania, but he ships around the whole USA), and he said that they would call it a **tray pack**, but most customers would simply say either **tray** or **package**.